# Image stored in react-native-fs doesnt show

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying to save an image to document directory (instead of cache) using react native and *react-native-fs* library, but instead I get a blank photo.

```js
const localPath = (image) => {
    console.log("Cache directory path is ", image)
    const fileName = image.split('/').pop();
    console.log('Filename is ',fileName)
    const newPath =  'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + fileName;
    console.log(newPath)

    // write the file
    RNFS.writeFile(newPath, image, 'base64')
      .then((success) => {
        console.log('IMG WRITTEN!');
        console.log(newPath)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    return newPath
  }
```

So I want to use this `newPath`

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: newPath }} />
```

but a blank photo appears..... If I pass the original path, then the photo is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `image` is a path to a file just use the [copyFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs?activeTab=readme#copyfilefilepath-string-destpath-string-promisevoid) method

```js
const localPath = (image) => {
    console.log('Cache directory path is ', image)
    const fileName = image.split('/').pop();
    console.log('Filename is ', fileName)
    const newPath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`; // You don't really need the `'file://` prefix
    console.log(newPath);

    // COPY the file
    RNFS.copyFile(image, newPath)
      .then((success) => {
        console.log('IMG COPIED!');
        console.log(newPath);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });

    return newPath
  }
```

There's also a [moveFile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs?activeTab=readme#movefilefilepath-string-destpath-string-promisevoid) that you can use to move the file instead of copying

`writeFile` is used to write content to a file

---

#### Note

The function you use to copy the image and return the `newPath` is not async - it would return the `newPath` immediately - possibly before the image is copied to the document directory - this might cause a problem if the `<Image>` tries to load it before the file is actually there.

I would only return the `newPath` after the image is actually copied

```js
const localPath = async (image) => {
  const newPath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;

  await RNFS.copyFile(image, newPath);

  return newPath;
}

// usage
const uri = await localPath(image);
```

Comment: Well, your solution gives me that error, [TypeError: _reactNativeFs.default.copy is not a function. Maybe it does something else.

Comment: Yep - it's `copyFile` like in the documentation, I'll update the answer

Comment: ` RNFS.copyFile` is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following solution worked for me. You have to **encode photo to base64** format with **[react-native-image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64)** package

```
import ImgToBase64 from 'react-native-image-base64';
const localPath = (image) => {
    console.log("Cache directory path is ", image)
    const fileName = image.split('/').pop();
    console.log('Filename is ', fileName)
    const newPath = 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/' + fileName;
    console.log(newPath)

    // write the file
    ImgToBase64.getBase64String(image)
      .then(base64String =>

        RNFS.writeFile(newPath, base64String, 'base64')
          .then((success) => {
            console.log('IMG WRITTEN: ', newPath);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          }))

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    return newPath
  }
```

Comment: Please check my answer - use copy instead of reading the file then creating a base64 string then writing that down. BTW you could just read the file as base64 string instead - using `RNFS.readFile(image, 'base64').then(base64String => ...`